# React Native With Flask web Socket implementation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

> I'm developing Socket connection between flask and React Native for my
>   Learning purpose So I tried to Implement it by referring  [this github
>   repo](https://github.com/etmoore/socketio-flask-react-chat)

**my app.js**

```
  import io from 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io'; 

   class App extends Component {
   constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.socket = io(`http://10.0.2.2:5000`)     

     this.socket.on('retrieve_active_users', () => {

            this.socket.emit('activate_user', { username: "test_user" })

      })

      this.socket.on('user_activated', (data) => {    
        console.log(data)
      })

}
```

**My app.py**

```
from flask_socketio import  SocketIO, join_room, leave_room, emit

@socketio.on('connect')
def connect():
  print('listening to connect')
  retrieve_active_users()


def retrieve_active_users():
  print("trigger")
  emit('retrieve_active_users')


@socketio.on('activate_user')
def on_active_user(data):
    user = data.get('username')
    emit('user_activated', {'user': user}, broadcast=True)  


@socketio.on('emission')
def emission(data):
    print('listen to emission')
    message = data['hello']
    emit('emission', message, broadcast=True)
```

**Problem is after i run my react-native app**

**in server side**

it only execute `print('listening to connect')` and `print("trigger")` lines infinitely

**in client side**

these lines are not execute

```
this.socket.on('user_activated', (data) => {    
    console.log(data)
})
```

and in console it shows

```
listening to connect  // print statements that i have added
trigger // print statements that i have added
127.0.0.1 - - [2020-02-02 12:16:38] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N04fglI HTTP/1.1" 200 349 0.029920
127.0.0.1 - - [2020-02-02 12:16:38] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N04fg_h HTTP/1.1" 400 162 0.000997
```

So i use react-native debugger and add `console.log(this.socket)` in side constructor it shows json object and inside that it mentioned

```
connected: false
disconnected: true
```

how can i solve these problem

thank you

Comment: Enable Socket.IO logs in the server, that will show some clues. To do this add `engineio_logger=True` and `logger=True` arguments to your `SocketIO()` object.

Comment: @Miguel now my log shows  `GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N0C2eMw HTTP/1.1" 200`  , `Invalid session None` , `POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N0C2eN_ HTTP/1.1" 400` and  `b05af575be8045928c73c97c1c79e123: Client is gone, closing socket`

Comment: Your client is not communicating with the server appropriately. This was actually reported already. See https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/716.

Comment: ya i saw that and i tried it but still problem not solved

Comment: Is this solved?

Comment: @ThanveerShah no